# Eventhandlers design

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Totaly design oriented question.

i have seen lots of examples that makes a custom event like this:

```
namespace 
{
    public delegate void NewClientEvent(object sender, EventArgs e);

    class ClientListner
    {
        public event NewClientEvent ClientConnected;
    }

}
```

but do it have to be like this ? what if i dont have eny use for either sender nor , is there then some reason to include it, or whould it be totaly legal to just do

```
namespace 
{
    public delegate void NewClientEvent(Socket newclient);

    class ClientListner
    {
        public event NewClientEvent ClientConnected;
    }

}
```

that way only the relevant data gets send ? vs intelisence helps with the inplimentation anyway, so it is not like it will get harder.

Comment: What's wrong with having the `object sender` parameter anyway?

Comment: If you are making your own events you can do whatever makes sense for your application. The `(object sender, EventArgs e)` pattern works really well for UI events, but you don't have to follow that pattern if something else works better.

Comment: For static events it is not necessary, but for instance events yes, it is a good thing to do. Otherwise you'll not be able to find who is raising the event(If not now, you may need it in future).

Comment: hmm for this aplication it aint really nessasary to know WHO raised it, i will come from the listner part of the server every time, however the clientlistner was just an exemple ^.^ it was ment to be on the broard basis, it is the 3rd time i make my own events for a subsystem. and i had asked my self this everytime, thx you Guys for the input :)

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be that way.  You can break the .NET Framework guidance, but you'll of course make it harder on the client programmer to know what you are trying to do and why you made it different.  Using *static* events is however a pretty universally bad idea, very fruitful source of memory leaks.

Comment: newe mind the static it was just an example, i dont use that code exactlty it was more meant as what whould be best practice here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `object sender, EventArgs e` for events, and `MyRelevantClass data` for callbacks.

My definition would be like this for this context: An event can originate from multiple places, and many entities can listen for it - each requiring (a subset of the) data. Callbacks are system specific, context specific and it is much closer to strongly coupled inheritance/polymorphism than it is loosely coupled messaging.

**Why sender and events?**

What if you suddenly need to know what part of your system caused the new client to connect? What if you want to add metadata to that particular connection? (were there any retries? do we know this IP? is it on the local network? do we want to override TTL? etc). Having the traditional `object sender, EventArgs e` signature makes it possible to cleanly extend your code with this functionality without having to rewrite code, except where you need the additional data.

For events it's important to prepare for a situation where you may need to add data, and you should try to stay within the [Open-Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).
The traditional signature makes this easier and is considered a best practice.

Comment: Thx Alexander actually explained it nicely :) ill look into the solid a bit more, barely scratched it.